# How can I use Eloquent ORM in Laravel when I have more than one id belonging to another table in a single row?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

When I send a query with Postman, the response looks like this:

[image: Error messages]

I'm pulling data like this from my 'series' table:

```
{
"id": 9770,
"name": "Name of serie",
"type": null,
"release_date": "2021-09-30 00:00:00",
"year": 2021,
"genre": "4,600,2815",
}
```

I want to include the relevant data that I extracted from the 'genres' table using the values in the 'genre' column in the main data under the name 'genres' in the main data.

This is what my 'Serie' and 'Genre' model looks like:

```
class Serie extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'series';

    public function genres()
    {
        $genreIds = explode(',', $this->genre);
        return Genre::whereIn('id', $genreIds)->get();
    }
}

class Genre extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'genres';
}
```

And I use it in Controller like this:

```
$page = $request->input('page', 1);
$perPage = $request->input('perPage', 10);

$allSeries = Serie::with('genres')->paginate($perPage, ['*'], 'page', $page);

return response()->json($allSeries, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

When I use the 'genres' function in the Serie model as follows, the query is successful, but the 'genres' data appears empty:

```
public function genres()
{
    $genreIds = explode(',', $this->genre);
    return $this->hasMany(Genre::class, 'id', 'genre')->whereIn('id', $genreIds);
}
```

I also tried using a method via query like below but it didn't work:

```
$query = Serie::query();

$query->with([
    'genres' => function ($query) {
        // genres ilişkisi için özel sorgular yapabilirsiniz
        $genreIds = explode(',', $this->genre);
        $query->whereIn('id', $genreIds);
    },
]);

$allSeries = $query->paginate($perPage, ['*'], 'page', $page);
```

I do not have the opportunity to add a column to the data in the Genres table indicating which main data they belong to.
How can I do this in Laravel?

Comment: You seem to have a comma separated list of related genres in your model. You can't define a relationship like that, you need to [normalise your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to [append an attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) to the JSON array:

```
class Serie extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'series';
    protected $appends = ['genres'];

    public function getGenresAttribute()
    {
        $genreIds = explode(',', $this->genre);
        return Genre::whereIn('id', $genreIds)->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

`with` callback function is not working when you return json response

you should build query like this:

```
$query = Serie::query();

$query->with(['genres']);

$query->whereHas('genres',function($q) {
       $genreIds = explode(',', $this->genre);
       $q->whereIn('id',$genreIds);
});

$allSeries = $query->paginate($perPage, ['*'], 'page', $page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent relations functions should return a relation not the actual data.
As it seems `genres` table doesn't have any foreign keys related to `series` table, using relations is not possible.

```php
class Serie extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'series';
    protected $appends = ['genres'];

    public function getGenresAttribute() {
        return Genre::whereIn('id', explode(',', $this->genre));
        // or if you prefer the Laravel way
        return Genre::whereIn('id', Str::of($this->genre)->explode(','));
    }
}
```

add `getGenreIdsAttribute()` method to get all the `Genre` models attached to the current `Serie` model and then add it to `appends` array. calling `$serie->genres` will call `getGenreAttribute()`
It will always gets appended to the `Serie` model response.

Then in your controller just query all `Serie` models

```php
$allSeries = Serie::paginate($perPage, ['*'], 'page', $page);
```

**PS.** This is not the best practice to store genre ids as comma separated values in `series` table. Loading each `Serie` will run 1 or more queries on the `Genre` table to get the genres. It's a common mistake and is famous for n+1 query problem.
Another table should hold the `genres` which associated which each `series`. It results in faster joins and better updating and everything. Then you can use `ManyToMany` Eloquent relation.

The table should look something like this.

`series_genres` table

| id | series_id | genre_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

each series can have multiple genres

Comment: When I explode this way, I get the following error message: "message": "Call to a member function explode() on string"

When I use it as in the comment below, the explode operation works without any problems

Comment: Sorry for the wrong syntax. Fixed the explode method in the answer.